# Setup EMR via AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr

Below is my code to setup EMR cluster:

```
public void createCluster(){
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxx","xxx");
        AmazonElasticMapReduceClient emr = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

        StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();

        StepConfig enableDebugging = new StepConfig()
            .withName("Enable Debugging")
            .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
            .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newEnableDebuggingStep());

        StepConfig installHive = new StepConfig()
            .withName("Install Hive")
            .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
            .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newInstallHiveStep());

       /* StepConfig hiveScript = new StepConfig().withName("Hive Script")
            .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
            .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newRunHiveScriptStep("s3://mywordcountbuckett/binary/WordCount.jar"));
            */

        RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
            .withName("Hive Interactive")
            .withAmiVersion("3.8")
            .withSteps(enableDebugging, installHive)

            .withLogUri("s3://mywordcountbuckett/")
            .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
            .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
            .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                .withEc2KeyName("mykeypair")
                .withInstanceCount(5)
                .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)
                .withMasterInstanceType("m3.xlarge")
                .withSlaveInstanceType("m1.large"));

        RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);
        System.out.println("This is result: " + result.toString());
```

The println prints out this:

```
This is result: {JobFlowId: j-10BX80MGWF3XQ}
```

Does this mean I have successfully created the cluster ? However when I tried to view from aws.amazon.com , there wasn't any cluster created.

And nothing was created in EC2 too.

Comment: from the console, are you looking to the correct region ?

Answer (score 0):

It was the region problem.

Placed this code and everything worked accordingly :

```
emr.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```